# Разбить svg на части

Tags: html, парсер, svg

Есть в меня в html 50+ тысяч строк кода с примерно такого вида

```html
<svg>
<defs>
    <linearGradient id="virus-protection-4d6fb6338df2">...</linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="video-hi-0d32c1b59850">...</linearGradient>
    ...
    <symbol id="warning-93da8c0b8b6d" data-name="...">...</symbol>
</defs>

 <symbol viewBox="0 0 160 160" id="icon-data"><title>data</title>
    <g id="data-cd1bd279" data-name="Data_ic">
        <polygon points="..." stroke-linecap="..." stroke-linejoin="..."></polygon>
        <polygon points="..." stroke-linejoin="..."></polygon>
    </g>
     <use id="...." data-name="Deal_ic_mid" xlink:href="#deals-mid-3584817d"></use>
 </symbol>
...
</svg>
```

Я думаю что это было сгенерировано какой то программой. Возможно ли как нибудь разбить это на отдельные файлы ибо вручную вытягивать это безумие. Писать парсер или регулярки тоже нет времени. Знаком с **svg** целых 40 минут. Как быть в таком случае? Возможно есть готовое решение?

Comment: а что вы с этим делаете дальше?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ ну подключать надо на страницах ка иконки, просто тянуть 5мб каждый раз не вариант

Comment: 1.будучи единожды загруженным, при настроенном должном образом кешированиии, файл не будет качаться второй раз. 2. Нарезать можно, нужно понимать по каким границам

Comment: @StrangerintheQ дело в том что данный код находиться не в отдельном файле а каждый раз он подключается в html и настроить кеширование нереально в таком случае. просто вытянуть все тэги symbol тож не вариант потому что они юзают какие-то общие градиенты, другие символы и т.д

Comment: можно его не встраивать в документ, а скачивать отдельно и потом разбирать, в таком случае кеширование поможет... , а что там? может ,snm проще нарисовать чем заимствовать?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ я вообще бэк но так случилось что надо мне с этим работать. Есть старая верстка и надо на новую перетянуть иконки оно работает но страница катастрофически долго грузиться.